# Как переместить базу данных android приложения на сервер?

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, digitalocean

В моем android-приложении есть база данных с пятью таблицами. Как разместить ее на сервере Digital Ocean и сделать так, чтобы приложение взаимодействовало с этой бд, а не с той, что на устройстве?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Определиться с выбором БД, т.к. sqlite плохо подходит для подключения множества пользователей со стандартными настройками (MariaDB, MySQL и т.д.) или активировать [Write-Ahead Log](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) в настройках sqlite, что позволит не блокировать файл БД при чтении/записи данных единственным процессом
2. Завести DNS-адрес для сервера, т.к. может быть в будущем придется сменить IP-адрес сервера или хостинг-провайдера
3. Внедрить библиотеку для подключения к выбранной БД в приложение
4. Поменять строку подключения в приложении
5. Протестировать работоспособность запросов с новой БД, при необходимости скорректировать текст запросов

Comment: почему не подойдет?

Comment: SQLite хранит всю базу данных (включая определения, таблицы, индексы и данные) в единственном стандартном файле на том компьютере, на котором исполняется программа. Простота реализации достигается за счёт того, что перед началом исполнения транзакции записи весь файл, хранящий базу данных, блокируется.   отсюда: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite

Comment: добавил ссылку про настройку, которая позволит sqlite не блокировать файл БД при чтении/записи